# the php codes don't run but my html code run correctly

Tags: php, dreamweaver

i want to start php programming.
i use Dreamweaver IDE and WAMP Server.
when i run codes, the php codes, doesn't execute.
when my html code, run correctly.
for example when i use the following code:

```
<html>
<head>Hello</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<?php
echo("echoString");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the "Hello" Message shows on the screen but "echoString" doesn't show.
my WAMP Server Installed and worked correctly.
i see the html output in my browser.
thanks

Comment: Does your File end with `*.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the file with .php extension instead of .html  like yourfilename.php and place the file in www folder , run it by going to

localhost/youfilename.php